# Cookiebot via GTM / no conversions in Google ADS

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, event-tracking, cookieconsent

I just implemented cookiebot via GTM and for some of my clients it stoped sending data to google ads, or sending just a fraction of what it should have sent.

I don t have server side tracking or 1 st cookies for the clients with the issues this is a common denominator, but from the clients with no server side just a few happend to have this issue, not all.

And is wierd bcs the tracking went wrong just after we implemented cookiebot, up untill that day everything was ok.

Can somebody land a hand? Maybe you guys meet this problem.

Thx

I tried manual / auto cookieblocking, tried importing from GA4 bcs there are no problems only g-ads broke. Tried moving the cookies from marketing to statistics.